# Maven build issues with io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.17.Final

Tags: spring-boot, solr, cassandra, spring-data

Can anyone pleasae hellp in resolving the maven application been struggling on it for long.
I am connecting to cassandra with spring boot application. Whenever we do a mvn clean package -DskipTests=true we get the following warning:-

[Clean Building screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLcAB.jpg)

and on running the application fails (java -jar target/DemoSearch-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar) and attached is the stacktrace.

```
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2;
> nested exception is 
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'cassandraCluster' defined in class path
> resource [org/springframework/boot/autoc
> onfigure/cassandra/CassandraAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean
> instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationExcept ion: Failed to
> instantiate [com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster]: Factory method
> 'cassandraCluster' threw exception; nested exception is
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/ netty/util/Timer
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0 .2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:579)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5 .0.2.RELEASE]
>         ... 40 common frames omitted Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'persistentEntities' defined in class path
> resource [org/springframewor
> k/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean
> instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstanti ationException: Failed to
> instantiate
> [org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentEntities]: Factory
> method 'persistentEntities' threw exception; nested exceptio n is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name
> 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.CassandraData
> AutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through
> constructor parameter 2; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'cassandraCluster' defined in class path
> resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cassandra/CassandraAutoConfiguration.class]:
> Bean insta ntiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster]: F actory method
> 'cassandraCluster' threw exception; nested exception is
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/util/Timer
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:587)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5 .0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1250)
> ~[spr ing-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099)
> ~[spring-beans-5 .0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RE LEASE.jar!/:5.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELE ASE.jar!/:5.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.2.RELEAS E]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:
> 5.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.resolveBeanReference(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:392)
> ~[spring-con text-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:364)
> ~[spring-context-5.0.2. RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4669ff6b.persistentEntities(<generated>)
> ~[spring-data-rest
> -webmvc-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.jsonSchemaConverter(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.java:426)
> ~[spring-data-rest-web mvc-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4669ff6b.CGLIB$jsonSchemaConverter$26(<generated>)
> ~[spring
> -data-rest-webmvc-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4669ff6b$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$553cc2af.invoke(<generate
> d>) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
> ~[spring-core-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361)
> ~[spring-context-5.0.2. RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4669ff6b.jsonSchemaConverter(<generated>)
> ~[spring-data-res t-webmvc-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0 .2.RELEASE]
>         ... 41 common frames omitted Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate
> [org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentEntities]: Factory
> method 'per sistentEntities' threw exception; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'org.springframewor
> k.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.CassandraDataAutoConfiguration':
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2;
> nested exception is org.springfram
> ework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with
> name 'cassandraCluster' defined in class path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cassan
> dra/CassandraAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory
> method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster]: Factory method
> 'cassandraCluster' threw exception; nested exception is
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/util/Time r
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0 .2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:579)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5 .0.2.RELEASE]
>         ... 63 common frames omitted Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name
> 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.Cassand
> raDataAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through
> constructor parameter 2; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'cassandraCluster' defined in class path
> resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cassandra/CassandraAutoConfiguration.class]:
> Bean  instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [com.datastax.driver.core.Clust er]: Factory method
> 'cassandraCluster' threw exception; nested exception is
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/util/Timer
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:729)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.2.RELEA SE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:192)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.2.RELEA SE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1270)
> ~[spring-beans-
> 5.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127)
> ~[spring-beans-5 .0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RE LEASE.jar!/:5.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELE ASE.jar!/:5.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.2.RELEAS E]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:
> 5.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5 .0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1250)
> ~[spr ing-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099)
> ~[spring-beans-5 .0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RE LEASE.jar!/:5.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELE ASE.jar!/:5.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.2.RELEAS E]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:
> 5.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:516)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.
> 0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:504)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.
> 0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1194)
> ~[spring-context-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.2 .RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:263)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.persistentEntities(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.java:236)
> ~[spring-data-rest-webm vc-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4669ff6b.CGLIB$persistentEntities$19(<generated>)
> ~[spring- data-rest-webmvc-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4669ff6b$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$553cc2af.invoke(<generate
> d>) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
> ~[spring-core-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361)
> ~[spring-context-5.0.2. RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4669ff6b.persistentEntities(<generated>)
> ~[spring-data-rest
> -webmvc-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0 .2.RELEASE]
>         ... 64 common frames omitted Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'cassandraCluster' defined in class path
> resource [org/springframework/
> boot/autoconfigure/cassandra/CassandraAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean
> instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantia tionException: Failed to
> instantiate [com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster]: Factory method
> 'cassandraCluster' threw exception; nested exception is
> java.lang.NoClassDefFound Error: io/netty/util/Timer
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:587)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5 .0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1250)
> ~[spr ing-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099)
> ~[spring-beans-5 .0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RE LEASE.jar!/:5.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELE ASE.jar!/:5.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.2.RELEAS E]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:
> 5.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.2.RELEASE ]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.ja r!/:5.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar! /:5.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:815)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.2. RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:721)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.2.RELEA SE]
>         ... 97 common frames omitted Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster]: Factory method
> 'cassandraCluster' threw except ion; nested exception is
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/util/Timer
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0 .2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:579)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5 .0.2.RELEASE]
>         ... 110 common frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/util/Timer
>         at com.datastax.driver.core.Configuration$Builder.build(Configuration.java:317)
> ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.3.2.jar!/:na]
>         at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Builder.getConfiguration(Cluster.java:1318)
> ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.3.2.jar!/:na]
>         at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:113) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.3.2.jar!/:na]
>         at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.buildFrom(Cluster.java:178)
> ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.3.2.jar!/:na]
>         at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Builder.build(Cluster.java:1335)
> ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.3.2.jar!/:na]
>         at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cassandra.CassandraAutoConfiguration.cassandraCluster(CassandraAutoConfiguration.java:86)
> ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2
> .0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>         at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cassandra.CassandraAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$26c07881.CGLIB$cassandraCluster$0(<generated>)
> ~[spring-bo
> ot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>         at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cassandra.CassandraAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$26c07881$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f566d5b3.invoke(<generat
> ed>)
> ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>         at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
> ~[spring-core-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361)
> ~[spring-context-5.0.2. RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cassandra.CassandraAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$26c07881.cassandraCluster(<generated>)
> ~[spring-boot-autoc
> onfigure-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0 .2.RELEASE]
>         ... 111 common frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.netty.util.Timer
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
>         at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:93)
> ~[DemoSearch-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
>         ... 127 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Looks like the spring boot framework which was used to develop spring data data for casandra is not matching with the spring boot jar that you have. Please use appropriate versions. <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency> and spring boot version to 1.5.8.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

Following is the pom.xml :-

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.demo.search</groupId>
    <artifactId>DemoSearch</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>DemoSearch</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-solr</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
         <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency> -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-all -->
<!-- <dependency>
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.9.Final</version>
</dependency>-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>16.0.1</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

     <repositories>
        <!-- <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository> -->
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `transitive dependency` warning because you are adding `netty-all jar` version which is different from jar version added by Spring boot. If you remove version number from the dependency then you will not get that warning. I don't have your Cassandra related files and your Spring boot file so I cannot see if I am getting ClassNotFoundException. But I used another class - `NetUtil` from `io.netty.util` package and I could load that class without any error.